# Flash error 1089

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, error-code

I have experienced error 1089, I am not sure how to fix it.
Here is all  my code:
I have never before seen this error and need to get it fixed, fast. So my game can be out in time.

```
import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent;

Phone.stop();

//Accelerometer?
if (Accelerometer.isSupported)
{
    myTextField.text = "Tilt to move.";

    var acell:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();  
    acell.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, update);
}
else
{
    myTextField.text = "No Accelerometer.";
}

var targetX:int = 0;
var targetY:int = 0;

function update (e:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
    character1.x = e.accelerationX*100
    character1.y = e.accelerationY*100
}

if (StageOrientation.DEFAULT)
{
    Phone.gotoAndPlay(2)
}
else (StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT)
{
    Phone.stop(1)       // error here but only here...
}
else (StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT)
{
    Phone.stop(1)
}
else (StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN)
{
    Phone.gotoAndPlay(2)
}
```

If anyone could be kind enough to help it would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
This is not vital, actually... As I can only release a pc version instead!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because I'm too long out of ActionScript...
But shouldn't

> if () {} else () {} else () {}

throw errors already?

I thought AS3 only accepted

```
if () 
{

} else if() {

} else {

}
```

If that's not the case, then show a bit more of your code and error message that's given to you.

Comment: Could you provide more of the code and/or error message then? It's all kind of vague at the moment.

Comment: Error 1089 means that there is else in a unexpected position.

Comment: Sorry, I have been without internet the past few days, it was horrible. 
But if it is an error about an unexpected else, you should try out my solution. 
Change all the else with conditions to:
} else if(condition) { 
The last one can be left without the if-statement, but only if you you want to execute code, that responds false with all above conditions.

Also check what StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT is. 
Cause it seems to me that this is not a boolean. But more a checking method as in:
if(StageOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT) {